# Uncaught exception PDO Exception, Can't bind param PHP

Tags: php, pdo

I try to bind an parameter to my PDO but I get an error.

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined.

I have an variable with:

```
$zoekopdracht = $_GET=["klant"];
```

And I'm trying to make a search box to search in a table in my database.

And here is my PDO:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM klanten WHERE pagina_id = :zoekopdracht ORDER BY klant_id ASC');
$stmt->bindParam(':zoekopdracht', $zoekopdracht, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute(array($klantenbeheer));
```

Comment: `$_GET=["klant"];` remove the `=`

Comment: `$stmt->execute(array($klantenbeheer));` -> `$stmt->execute();` maybe? + ^

Comment: @Rizier123 Mix of both ;-)

Comment: Comment #1 + comment #2 = La soluzione

Comment: Aw... didn't saw that with the $_GET... Still get the error :(

Comment: @Jordy and you still get the error when using `$stmt->execute()` ?

Comment: Solved it! Just used the questions mark to bind the parameter and change to execute(), thanks for your help!